# How to administer, manage & update 40 to 50 Kubuntu laptops?

Tags: kubuntu, ssh, remote-access, administration, remote-control

I have a custom developed application presently running on about 40 Kubuntu laptops (& more planned). Every few months I have to update the application. I also have to run Ubuntu updates and a few other minor things. I've been doing it manually, one by one, using Team Viewer to log into each client. I would like to dramatically improve this process.

Can anyone suggest an approach (and tools)? This is not an enterprise, I am not a sysadmin, and I prefer a simple solution.

To update my application presently, I have to use command line tools (as root) and I have to have access to the GUI in order to run the application. Team Viewer allows me to do this.

My question is, "How can I automate the process of updating my custom application on 40+ laptops?"

I'm most familiar with bash scripts and SSH.

As far as what have I considered or investigated so far, I googled a bit and the names of Puppet & Chef came up. But I read this:

> People have been advocating tools like Chef and Puppet for solving
>   exactly those problems. Both of them are solid tools, but they can be
>   quite daunting.

So those options are not for me.

I also heard about [Sprinkle](http://blog.thecodepath.com/2011/08/26/forget-chef-or-puppet-automate-with-sprinkle/), but I'm not provisioning servers - I'm managing laptops.

I came across Cuisine next:

http://stackful-dev.com/cuisine-the-lightweight-chefpuppet-alternative.html
https://github.com/sebastien/cuisine#readme

> Fabric is an incredible tool to automate administration of remote
>   machines. As Fabric's functions are rather low-level, you'll probably
>   quickly see a need for more high-level functions such as add/remove
>   users and groups, install/upgrade packages, etc.
>
> Cuisine is a small set of functions that sit on top of Fabric, to
>   abstract common administration operations such as file/dir operations,
>   user/group creation, package install/upgrade, making it easier to
>   write portable administration and deployment scripts.

Still, it sounds like I would have to learn Python to use Cuisine. I'm willing to do that if it is the right solution.

But I would like to ask here if there is a simpler way.

Comment: I hope you get an answer because I am also looking for something like that, though i need it for fewer machines. :)

Comment: @semi-newbie Salt Stack (http://saltstack.com/) is looking the most interesting. Ansible sounds interesting too. But I don't have any final solution yet...

Comment: You need to look into parellel execution tools like: MCollective, Ansible, SaltStack to do this. Even Puppet or Chef to manage the configuration and do automation stuff.